# CUPS Printer failing to print out any paper

Tags: raspbian, cups

I have a Samsung printer that I have been trying to make Google Cloud Print compatible. The GCP CUPS Connector is working well, but my printer is not sending out any paper. It acts as if it is printing, but it does nothing. It is a Samsung ML-2545. When I plug it into the Raspberry Pi, it believes that it is a ML-85 printer. The pictures of the printers seem pretty close when you look at it, but it is not working. I messed with the media source settings for a bit, but to no avail. Currently, my printer seems to be working, but it does not print anything out. I could not find a PPD. I am running Raspbian Jessie on an RPI1 Model B. I am running CUPS v1.7.5. What do you recommend that I do? Please help if you can.

**UPDATE:** I tried installing the official ULD for my printer, but it said that it did not recognize `armhf`.

**UPDATE 2:** I found a good-ish answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38310/43865), but I do not know how to "hack" the install file. I am a bit of a n00b. ;)

**UPDATE 3:** I noticed that [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27522/43865) was better, but I have a hard-float distro of Raspbian. The setup process was hard for me anyways, so I do not know what to do.

Comment: Why do we need a picture of your printer if you have provided full details of all the equipment you have used? The picture does not include physical connections to the printer for example.

Comment: Got rid of picture.